# php facebook sdk get user's birthday

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

in php/server side I need to get user's birthday, heres my code:

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) {
    // Fetch the viewer's basic information
    $basic = $facebook->api('/me');
    var_dump($basic);
}
```

'$basic' gives me an array with these keys:
id, name, first_name, last_name, link, username, gender, timezone, locale, updated_time

and heres what I have in my fb app's permissions:
email, user_birthday, publish_actions

now why isn't there the 'birthday' key in that array???

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to add in the basic array also that you require the user_birthday also. Another problem can be wit the user permission. There are cases were users don't give you permission to get their birthday.

Comment: im testing it with my other facebook account

Comment: is it working ? Let me know because I have a working sdk and I will check the code there How i did it exactly